# Select distinct column in sql group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following rows:

```
DateTime    Item_no     Vo_No
2019-06-27  30322264    0118113
2017-12-27  00265929    0242712
2019-01-21  30322264    0515768
2017-12-27  00265929    0400026
2019-01-21  30322264    0569606
2018-09-25  00265929    0696864
2019-01-21  30317757    0696619
2019-06-27  30317757    0118113
2017-12-27  00265929    0242624
2017-01-24  00265929    0282971
2019-01-21  30317757    0386202
2019-01-21  30317757    0515706
2019-01-21  30322264    0696619
2017-12-27  00265929    0242625
2017-12-27  00265929    0395347
2017-12-27  00265929    0441449
2019-01-21  30317757    0569605
2017-12-27  00265929    0282972
2017-01-24  00265929    0282984
2019-01-21  30322264    0397256
```

I'm trying to get the distinct item no, with the latest date and the vo_no.

I have came up with the following query:

```
 SELECT MAX(b.upd_dtime), b.item_no 
 FROM vo_item_t b JOIN (
     SELECT a.vo_no, a.vo_state, a.vo_confirm_date, a.vo_order_date 
     FROM vo_order_t a) y ON y.vo_no = b.vo_no and b.item_No IN(30317757, 30322264, 00265929) 
 GROUP BY b.item_no
```

It works pretty well, I get the following result:

```
Date        Item_No
2019-06-27  30322264
2019-06-27  30317757
2018-09-25  00265929
```

But as you can see, the vo_no is missing for each Item_No, so I tried the following:

```
 SELECT MAX(b.upd_dtime), b.item_no, y.vo_no 
 FROM vo_item_t b JOIN (
     SELECT a.vo_no, a.vo_state, a.vo_confirm_date, a.vo_order_date 
     FROM vo_order_t a) y ON y.vo_no = b.vo_no and b.item_No IN(30317757, 30322264, 00265929) 
 GROUP BY b.item_no, y.vo_no
```

As you can see, I added y.vo_no in the select and the group by. But the result from query is the following:

```
2019-06-27  30322264    0118113
2017-12-27  00265929    0242712
2019-01-21  30322264    0515768
2017-12-27  00265929    0400026
2019-01-21  30322264    0569606
2018-09-25  00265929    0696864
2019-01-21  30317757    0696619
2019-06-27  30317757    0118113
2017-12-27  00265929    0242624
2017-01-24  00265929    0282971
2019-01-21  30317757    0386202
2019-01-21  30317757    0515706
2019-01-21  30322264    0696619
2017-12-27  00265929    0242625
2017-12-27  00265929    0395347
2017-12-27  00265929    0441449
2019-01-21  30317757    0569605
2017-12-27  00265929    0282972
2017-01-24  00265929    0282984
2019-01-21  30322264    0397256
```

The distinct on item_no don't work any more.

So my question is: how can I also get the vo_no for the distinct item_no?

Comment: Sample data values like 1, 2 and 3 is so much easier to read than 0569606, 0569406 and 0569605. Make it easy to assist you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an inner join to solve this. There could be an easier way but for now this should work

```
select x.*,y.vo_no from (
 SELECT MAX(b.upd_dtime) as MaxT, b.item_no as Item_NO
 FROM vo_item_t b JOIN (
     SELECT a.vo_no, a.vo_state, a.vo_confirm_date, a.vo_order_date 
     FROM vo_order_t a) y ON y.vo_no = b.vo_no and b.item_No IN(30317757, 30322264, 00265929) 
 GROUP BY b.item_no
)x 
INNER JOIN
vo_order_t y
ON x.MaxT = y.Date
AND x.Item_NO = y.Item_No
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I think I was wrong. I would like to use MAX(upd_dtime) from the vo_order_t-table, not the vo_item_t table..

Comment: just change the table name from vo_item to vo_order provided it has the columns to join

Answer (score 1):

There's also this solution:

```
    select item_no, max(datetime) mxdt, max(vo_no) keep(dense_rank first order by datetime desc) vo_no
    from (select '2019-06-27' datetime,  30322264 item_no,   0118113 vo_no from dual union
    select '2017-12-27',  00265929 ,   0242712 from dual union
    select '2019-01-21',  30322264 ,   0515768 from dual union
    select '2017-12-27',  00265929 ,   0400026 from dual union
    select '2019-01-21',  30322264 ,   0569606 from dual union
    select '2018-09-25',  00265929 ,   0696864 from dual union
    select '2019-01-21',  30317757 ,   0696619 from dual union
    select '2019-06-27',  30317757 ,   0118113 from dual union
    select '2017-12-27',  00265929 ,   0242624 from dual union
    select '2017-01-24',  00265929 ,   0282971 from dual union
    select '2019-01-21',  30317757 ,   0386202 from dual union
    select '2019-01-21',  30317757 ,   0515706 from dual union
    select '2019-01-21',  30322264 ,   0696619 from dual union
    select '2017-12-27',  00265929 ,   0242625 from dual union
    select '2017-12-27',  00265929 ,   0395347 from dual union
    select '2017-12-27',  00265929 ,   0441449 from dual union
    select '2019-01-21',  30317757 ,   0569605 from dual union
    select '2017-12-27',  00265929 ,   0282972 from dual union
    select '2017-01-24',  00265929 ,   0282984 from dual union
    select '2019-01-21',  30322264 ,   0397256 from dual)
    group by item_no
    order by item_no
```

which gives this on your data:

```
       ITEM_NO MXDT            VO_NO
    ---------- ---------- ----------
        265929 2018-09-25     696864
      30317757 2019-06-27     118113
      30322264 2019-06-27     118113
```

(look up [this doc page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/FIRST.html#GUID-85AB9246-0E0A-44A1-A7E6-4E57502E9238) )